# How to distinguish a file from a directory in command prompt (cmd)?

Tags: file, command-line, directory

I need to write a script based on whether what I am reading is a file or directory. Basically I have a txt file which contains paths of files + directories, I am reading this file as follows:  `FOR /f %%i IN (root.txt) DO (call :output %%i)`

I need to call :output which will output only the files contained in the txt file.
so if root.txt contains:

> C:\TEST
>    C:\TEST\test.txt
>    C:\TEST\TEST2\test2.txt

The output should be:

> C:\TEST\test.txt
>   C:\TEST\TEST2\test2.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/219050/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-windows) to find out how to test if something is a directory.

You basically have to append `\` to the end, and then use `If Exist`; so your script becomes:

```
FOR /f %%i IN (root.txt) DO IF NOT EXIST "%%i\" (call :output %%i)
```

Comment: There is still one small problem I am suffering with, which is when the path contains a space for example: C:\Program Files\test.txt then it will Print: C:\Program

Comment: @Wael: Did you put quotes around it?

Comment: yes, even if the file contains the following: "C:\Program Files\test.txt" I have same issue.

Comment: @Wael: Ooh I see -- I think you need the `delims` option. Take a look [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/delims-t1466398.html); I haven't done it myself (don't have a Windows computer in front of me right now) but I think you need to set the delimiter to be a newline rather than a space.